# How to set common part of route (Prefix) from config.json for all Actions in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with Route attribute as well as every Action with it`s own Route like:

```
[Route("api/version/v1")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   [Route("receipts/verifyReceipt")]
   public IActionResult VerifyReceipt(...){....}
   
   ...... several actions with diffrent Routes

}
```

My aim is to have api route : 'api/version/v1/receipts/verifyReceipt'

How can I set prefix `[Route("api/version/v1")]` from config.json

I`ve tried to set it up from Startupt.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute( "default",  apiCommon.Value);
        });
```

where 'apiCommon.Value' is my prefix 'api/version/v1' While adding route attribute to MyController:

```
[Route("", Name = "default")]
```

But that seems to have no effect. And api route looks like this: '/receipts/verifyReceipt'

Any Ideas what I`am doing wrong?

Comment: You wanna define routes from config.json, right?

Comment: Only common part, I have 2 api services, etc: 'open/api/version...' &  'api/version...'. 
I want to be able to set this part of Route in config.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my problem on [Global route prefixing in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/)

Answer (score 2):

I think **`UsePathBase()`** fits your needs best. It does routing after the pathbase use specified

call it before **`app.UseRouting()`**

```cs
app.UsePathBase(apiCommon.Value);
```

Comment: Seems like it has no effect... Does it require any modifications in Controller?